# print statement not working in a Spark standalone cluster of 3 nodes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark stand-alone cluster (3 nodes) where the driver program is running on the master (1 node) and there are 3 executors (2 slaves and 1 on master node).

I have a few basic questions:
1. I want to find out the execution time of each and every mapPartition function executed by the worker nodes programmatically and not through spark UI. I tried time.time() but it's not working - even the logging for some reason is not working. I looked at the logs for print statement and nothing was found. Here's my code:

```
def bar(x):
    start_time = time.time()
    res_list = # do something and store result as an iterator in res_list
    print(time.time() - start_time)
    return res_list

def foo():
    li = list(range(0, 10000000))
    test_rdd = sc.parallelize(li)
    test_rdd = test_rdd.repartition(200)

    res_rdd = test_rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: bar(x))

    res_df = spark.createDataFrame(res_rdd, cols)

    '''
    write spark dataframe to mongodb
    '''
```

2. Is there a package/tool out there that can help us get the time? Basically, our code is much more complicated - as it reads from a database into a dataframe, do some computation, write it back to the database and we need to get timing breakdown for each of the steps.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where are you calling the foo()?  Dont see any call to run foo() which in turn should call bar() to print the statements.  Also, what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: when you say "you looked at the logs" where did you look? Only on the master logs or also on the executor logs?

Comment: On Scala class "CollectionAccumulator" can be used for get values on Driver node. Values can be tuple: partitionId->time. Partition id in "mapPartitions" can be received with "TaskContext.getPartitionId"

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [Spark History Server](https://supergloo.com/spark-monitoring/spark-performance-monitoring-history-server/) or [spark.time()](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2017-03-measuring-apache-spark-workload-metrics-performance-troubleshooting).